# Grouping and sorting weighted values by rank

Tags: python, list, algorithm, sorting

I have data consisting of several values.  Each value has a positive weight and a rank.  I would like to return a sublist of these values such that values are added by increasing rank to the list until the sum of their weights is the smallest possible greater or equal to a given target, with the additional constraint that if a value is added, all of those with that same rank must be added, ie values are added to the list by ranking group.

I have written the alogorithm below, which is quite slow and not so easy to read.  The input is a list of tuples (we can assume it is already sorted by rank); each tuple contains rank, value and weight.  All that needs to be returned is the list of kept values, and their total weight.  The algorithm groups the data by rank, then figures out how many ranks to add to reach the proper cumulative weight.  Any suggestions to accelerate and improve?

For the input list `[(1, 'a', 0.10131488885239891), (1, 'b', 0.05189220940446056), (1, 'c', 0.05233086643211586), (4, 'd', 0.019651238401109394), (5, 'e', 0.11439063810128784), (6, 'f', 0.003242047085661822), (6, 'g', 0.03093925229983648), (8, 'h', 0.09737202015393008), (8, 'i', 0.02024957487257707), (10, 'j', 0.08454098571100034), (11, 'k', 0.18524611312188527), (11, 'l', 0.07110968996322396), (11, 'm', 0.023236464232769254), (14, 'n', 0.14448401136774303)]` and target weight `0.47`, it returns the sublist `['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i']` and kept weight `0.49138273560337803`.

```
weightGoal = 0.47 # Target weight
    
# Example of data; each tuple has (rank, value and weight)
individualData = [(1, 'a', 0.10131488885239891), (1, 'b', 0.05189220940446056), (1, 'c', 0.05233086643211586), (4, 'd', 0.019651238401109394), (5, 'e', 0.11439063810128784), (6, 'f', 0.003242047085661822), (6, 'g', 0.03093925229983648), (8, 'h', 0.09737202015393008), (8, 'i', 0.02024957487257707), (10, 'j', 0.08454098571100034), (11, 'k', 0.18524611312188527), (11, 'l', 0.07110968996322396), (11, 'm', 0.023236464232769254), (14, 'n', 0.14448401136774303)]
print("Input", individualData, weightGoal)

# Determine cumulative weight for each value.
vCumulWeight = [0]
for ind in individualData: vCumulWeight.append(vCumulWeight[-1] + ind[-1])
vCumulWeight.pop(0)

# To group by rank    
ranks = list(set([v[0] for v in individualData])) # Unique values of the rank
ranks.sort(reverse=False) # Sort the list by rank
rankWeights = [] # Total weight of values with same rank
rankValues = [] # Values with same rank

# Group points by rank
for r in ranks:
    rankW, rankV = 0, []
    for ind in individualData:
        if r == ind[0]:
            rankW += ind[-1]
            rankV.append(ind[1])
    rankWeights.append(rankW)
    rankValues.append(rankV)
    
# Get cumulative weight of each group
rankCumulWeight = [0]
for op in rankWeights: rankCumulWeight.append(rankCumulWeight[-1] + op)
rankCumulWeight.pop(0)

# Rank all values and all groups
fullRankingVals, fullRankingGroups, rnk, prevLen, prevCP = [], [], 0, 1, 0
for i, (o, pr, ov, cp) in enumerate(zip(ranks, rankWeights, rankValues, rankCumulWeight)):
    fullRankingGroups.append((i+1, ov, o, pr, cp, ((cp <= weightGoal) or (prevCP < weightGoal))))
    rnk += prevLen
    for v in ov: fullRankingVals.append((rnk, v, o, pr/len(ov), cp, ((cp <= weightGoal) or (prevCP < weightGoal))))
    prevLen = len(ov)
    prevCP = cp

print("============ Check by value")
for v in fullRankingVals: print(v)
print("============ Check by group")
for v in fullRankingGroups: print(v)
print("============")

## Actual acceptance
tmpAccepted = [v for v in fullRankingVals if (v[-1])]
acceptedValues = [v[1] for v in tmpAccepted]
accdeptedWeight = max(v[-2] for v in tmpAccepted)
print("Result", acceptedValues, accdeptedWeight)
```

Comment: Does this need to be done without pandas?

Comment: Pandas can be used

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With `Pandas`:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(l, columns=['rank', 'value', 'weight'])
df = df.groupby('rank').agg({'value': list, 'weight': sum})

m = ~((df.weight.cumsum() > 0.47).shift(
    fill_value=False))

result = df[m]['value'].explode().to_list()
weight = df[m]['weight'].cumsum().iloc[-1]
```

Comment: Thanks.  This returns the proper sublist, but not sure how to get the cumulative weight of the sublist.

Comment: @MisterMak updated code to include weight as well.

Comment: This is both more concise and faster than what I had.

Answer (score 1):

Might I suggest that you take the easiest approach possible, and just solve the problem in small chunks?

Let's break it down into 3 small steps so that you get to follow along what is actually happening:

1. Sort the data in ascending order using `rank` as a key.
2. Add data to our `storage` until we reach the limit `weightGoal`
3. If the `weightGoal` is reached, add to our `storage` if the `value` is the same as the last one we added to our `storage`

Now let's code the above flow:

```
weightGoal = 0.47 # Target weight
    
# Example of data; each tuple has (rank, value and weight)
individualData = [(1, 'a', 0.10131488885239891), (1, 'b', 0.05189220940446056), (1, 'c', 0.05233086643211586), (4, 'd', 0.019651238401109394), (5, 'e', 0.11439063810128784), (6, 'f', 0.003242047085661822), (6, 'g', 0.03093925229983648), (8, 'h', 0.09737202015393008), (8, 'i', 0.02024957487257707), (10, 'j', 0.08454098571100034), (11, 'k', 0.18524611312188527), (11, 'l', 0.07110968996322396), (11, 'm', 0.023236464232769254), (14, 'n', 0.14448401136774303)]

# step 1
individualData.sort(key=lambda x: x[0])

storage = 0
last = None
for data in individualData:
    if storage < weightGoal:  # step 2
        last = data
        storage += data[2]
    elif last and data[1] == last[1]:  # step 3
        storage += data[2]
        # no need to change `last` here unless you really want to
    else:  # termination clause
        break
```

Now the final `summation` is stored in the `storage` variable and you also get the bonus of knowing which element was the last to add using the `last` variable.

Let me know if there's any ambiguity.

Comment: Thanks!  The loop exits a bit too early (ends at 'h' rather than 'i').  Also, from ```last```, how does one obtain the list of elements up to and including it?

Comment: @MisterMak Try to save the elements in another array and you'll have all the saved elements. Good luck.